# Meanings of the + and - signs in an expression

Tags: abstract-algebra

Sorry if it's a dumb question but i must make things clear to me. So, let's say we have an expression like `2 + 3`. The purpose of the `+` sign is to represent addition of the numbers `+2` and `+3` (we don't write down the the 2 + signs). Or let's say we have this expression: `2 - 3`. We can write this expression like this: `2 + (-3)` because of the definition of subtraction (am i right?). So, in the expression `2 + 3` the `+` sign had the meaning of "addition" and in the second expression the `-` sign represented the sign of the number (because we're dealing with integers). Is this reasoning ok or i am wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. But keep in mind that everyone might not think like this. For example, someone might translate $3+5$ as $3-(-5).$ I personally think that sign manipulation is for one to make sense of expressions they might not be understanding.

Comment: @codenshit : I think it is better to think of $-$ in $2-3$ as a binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

In both expressions (2+3, 2-3), the signs + and - means addition and subtraction respectively. An expression is a sequence of operands separated by operators (using programming language terms). It is grossly simplified since 2y doesn't have an operator. It will be confusing if the symbol means and operator in one place and sign in the other. That's where parenthesis comes in to remove ambiguity.

Comment: `Ordinarily a ring only has two operations defined on it; in the case of the integers, these are addition and multiplication. A ring already has the concept of additive inverses, but it does not have any notion of a separate subtraction operation, so the use of signed addition as subtraction allows us to apply the ring axioms to subtraction without needing to prove anything.` - from wikipedia

Comment: @codenshit: Your question didn't talk about rings, etc. It was a simple question whether the - refers to the operator or the sign. For me in a simple context I will consider - in 2 - 3 as an operator. Probably your question was asked in a different context which was not clear in the question.

Comment: it says that there is no separate subtraction operation it's just addition. So according to this subtraction doesn't have an operator because it's defined through addition. Am i wrong?

Comment: @codenshit: Check the title of that paragraph, it is talking about a particular case where subtraction is done by addition and it is talking about separate topic of Rings. Only here subtraction is done through addition. From the same paragraph - `One solution is to view subtraction as addition of signed numbers`